# How do I calculate limits of transfer functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a transfer function, let's say `G=1/(1+s*0.23)` and want to know the limit of that transfer function.

That means I want to calculate:

```
x(inf)=lim g(t) =  lim {1/s * G}
        t-> inf     s->0
```

How can I do this with MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [dcgain](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dcgain.html)

Answer (score 0):

The "Linear Time Invariant (LTI) System Object"module for the Control System Toolbox has a lot of neat functions to analyse LTI systems :

```
G = 1/(1=s*0.23);
T = ss(G);
y = step(T)
```

`y[-1]` give you the limit you're looking for.